# Evaluation of expressions like if( argv[1][0] != ~'t')

Tags: c, if-statement

I have to input a string to make the second if condition false and print "Correct!". Can it be done?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

 if(argc != 2) { // argc is how long argv is, including that path-to-self
     puts("You need to give me exactly one argument!");
     return -1;

   }
// argv[1] represents the command line input you have given to the program. Which is a string or a char array.

 if(argv[1][0] != ~'t' || argv[1][1] != ~'h' || argv[1][2] != ~'e') {
      puts("noooo!");
      return 0;
    }
 else printf("Correct!\n");

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: "the" is not the answer right? And ~'t' doesn't evaluate to a character.

Answer (score 0):

If an argument is passed to the program (i.e. the first `argc != 2` check doesn't fail) then the expression `argv[1][0] != ~'t'` will *always* be true (as well as the other checks but those won't be made because of [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)).

The expression `~'t'` will first be converted to an `int` ([see this reference for why](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions), the same thing will happen to `argv[1][0]`). That means you will have `~0x00000074` (if using the [ASCII alphabet](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) and 32-bit `int`). That will evaluate as `0xffffff8b`.

It doesn't matter what argument you give your program, `argv[1][0]` will *never* be equal to `0xffffff8b` and so the condition is true.

Comment: They can compare as equal if `char` is signed.

Comment: @interjay Only if the character is `0x8b`, and in normal standard ASCII that's not possible (it's a 7-bit encoding).

Comment: `char` is normally 8 bits, so use a character from outside ASCII. It should certainly be possible on all common platforms.

Comment: `'t'` is actually already of type `int`. The C language is irrational in many ways.